# next js server actions not show in data list

Tags: typescript, next.js, fetch, server-action

I successfully run my add function but when I check in the list it does not want to add the data that I have added earlier

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { createPost } from "./actions";
import { SubmitButton } from "./submitButton";
async function getPosts() {
  const res = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/posts/search?q=&limit=0&skip=0", { cache: 'no-store' });
  const {posts} = await res.json();
  return posts;
}
const FormPost = async ({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) => {
  const data = await getPosts()

  return (
    <>
      <form action={createPost}>
        <input type="text" name="title" className="border" />
        <input type="text" name="body" className="border" />
        <input type="text" name="userId" className="border" />
        <input type="text" name="tags" className="border" />
        <input type="text" name="reactions" className="border" />
        <SubmitButton />
      </form>
      <div className="p-10 flex flex-wrap gap-5">
        {data.map((d: any, index: any) => (
          <div key={index} className="p-1 shadow">
            <p>{d.body.slice(0, 5)}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default FormPost;
```

[its my action]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdtiW.png

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [dummyjson documentation](https://dummyjson.com/docs/posts#:%7E:text=Adding%20a%20new%20post%20will%20not%20add%20it%20into%20the%20server.), making a **POST** request to add a post only simulates a response. It will NOT add a new post to the database and fetching the post list will only return the default posts and not the created ones (as they are not added to the post database).